# Autoruns compare?

Tags: windows-10, malware, services, monitoring

Can someone explain better what I'm looking at when doing a comparison in Autoruns? I understand changes are highlighted in green so what are the red entries? Why would there be so many changes with services since the last comparison file that I took?

[image]

Comment: I guess that green entries are present currently but not in dump you're comparing to, while red entries are missing currently but present in dump. It also seems to me that Autoruns doesn't actually show entries that have changed - instead it shows that old one is missing and new one was added (eg. Origin Client Service near the bottom)

Comment: Hmm apparently green entries should be changes in the dump your comparing it to. Do you think Origin is showing older and newer installed versions?

Comment: "Apparently" - according to what? Yes, I think Origin's binary has been replaced by a new version with a different timestamp.

Comment: According to HowtoGeek: http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/using-autoruns-tool-to-track-startup-applications-and-add-ons/

Comment: A quote from that article: *"Now Autoruns will update the list with bright green anywhere there is a *new entry* in the list"*. They also state that *"It doesn’t show items that no longer exist in the current configuration"* but the article is quite old (2007 I think), I suppose red entries are items that were removed. And as I said, I guess it treats edited entries as removing old one (red) and adding a new one (green).

Comment: So red are ones that have been edited or replaced and green ones are completely new? In the pic above the green and red don't seem to have any relation to one another, I mean it's not like the green and red are showing both files that were edited, except for the Origin ones. This is kind of confusing.